Sup of a continuous function over a rectangular region
Suppose I have a continuous function $f$ on $K \times \mathbb{R}$ where $K$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, such that $\sup_{y \in \mathbb{R}} f(x,y)$ is finite for all $x$ (so component wise bounded). Does it follow that $f$ is also bounded on $K \times \mathbb{R}$ ?
Is the $\sup_{y \in \mathbb{R}} f(x,y)$ function continuous over $K$?

Pick $\varphi\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\varphi\geq 0$ and not identically zero, but $\varphi(x)=0$ for $\vert x \vert \leq 1$. Define $$ f(x,y) = \begin{cases} \frac{y}{\vert x \vert} \varphi(y/\vert x \vert),& x\neq 0, \ 0,& x=0. \end{cases} $$

Or even better $f(x,y) = y \varphi(y-1/\vert x \vert)$ for $x\neq 0$ and $f(0,y)=0$.

@SeverinSchraven Thank you for the example, I'm staring at the first one and wondering if the first factor of y is needed?

It is not really needed. The picture I had in mind was the second example (i.e. a bump which escapes to infinity as $x$ approaches $0$), where the factor is needed. Also, my mind jumped directly to $K=[0,1]^n$... that's why I keep talking about zero.

@SeverinSchraven Thank you for the explanation, I've been trying to visualize this function. Please tell me if my intuition of your idea correct, so essentially we are creating a hill with ever growing height along y, with a valley in the center (x=0) that gets more narrow as y tends to infinity, but because for any fixed y the width of the valley is still finite, it is continuous with f(0,y) = 0.

The intuition is that we moving the hill to infinity when approaching $x=0$. And we do this fairly quickly. So for every point $(0,y)$ there exists a small neighborhood such that the function vanishes. For every fixed $x>0$ I would like the fill to be of the order of $1/x$ (i.e. finite, but growing for $x\rightarrow 0^+$). On the other hand, I would like the hill to disappear in the limit by moving it to infinity.

At first I just wanted to show that $\sup_{y\in \mathbb{R}} f(x,y)$ is not continuous. The question is essentially does pointwise convergence (we know $f$ is continuous) imply uniform convergence. The standard counterexample in calculus $$ f_n: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f_n(x) = \begin{cases} nx,& x\in (0,1/n), \ 2-nx,& x\in [1/n, 2/n), \ 0,& \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$ also uses this idea of a hill which disappears. Instead of having a discrete index set I tried to come up with some continuous version. To render it continuous I had to make it disappear at infinity not at zero.

If $K$ is finite, then $\sup_{y\in \mathbb{R}} f(x,y)$ is continuous and $\sup_{x\in K} \sup_{y\in \mathbb{R}} f(x,y)$ is finite.
Assume now that $K$ is not finite. As $K$ is compact, it is bounded. As $K$ has infinitely many elements, $K$ must admit an accumulation point $x_0$.
Set $\varphi:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ via $\varphi(z)=\max\{ 1-\vert z \vert, 0\}$. Note that $\varphi$ is continuous, vanishes outside of $B(0,1)$ and $\max_{\mathbb{R}} \varphi =1=\varphi((0,\dots, 0))$.
Now define
$$ f: K\times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(x,y) = \begin{cases} \vert y \vert \varphi(y-1/\vert x-x_0\vert),& x\neq x_0, \\ 0,& x=x_0.\end{cases} $$
Clearly, $f$ is continuous away from $x=x_0$. On the other hand, close to $x=x_0$ the function is continuous as $\varphi(x,y)=0$ for $\vert x -x_0\vert \leq \frac{1}{\vert y \vert+1}$. Furthermore, we have for $x\neq x_0$
$$ \sup_{y\in \mathbb{R}} f(x,y) = \sup_{y\in \mathbb{R}} \vert y \vert \varphi(y-1/\vert x-x_0\vert) = \sup_{y\in \mathbb{R} \ : \ \vert y -1/\vert x -x_0\vert\vert \leq 1} \vert y\vert \varphi(y-1/\vert x-x_0\vert) \leq \frac{1}{\vert x-x_0\vert} +1 <\infty $$
where we have used that $0\leq \varphi \leq 1$. On the other hand, we have for $x\neq x_0$
$$ \sup_{y\in \mathbb{R}} f(x,y) \geq f(x,1/\vert x-x_0\vert) = 1/\vert x-x_0\vert. $$
Thus, we get, as $x_0$ is an accumulation point of $K$ that
$$ \sup_{x\in K} \sup_{y\in \mathbb{R}} f(x,y)=\infty. $$
In particular, this shows that $\sup_{y\in \mathbb{R}} f(x,y)$ is not a continuous function.
In fact, even if we would assume that $f$ would remain bounded, we would not get that $\sup_{y\in \mathbb{R}} f(x,y)$ is continuous. To see this, we can rerun the same construction with $\tilde{f}(x,y) = \varphi(y-1/\vert x-x_0\vert)$ for $x\neq x_0$ and $\tilde{f}(x_0,y)=0$. Then, we have
$$\sup_{y\in \mathbb{R}} \tilde{f}(x,y) = \begin{cases} 1,& x\neq x_0, \\ 0,& x=x_0, \end{cases}$$
which is not continuous.
